# Adding relative position to container div with absolute positioned children does not allow full width

Tags: html, css

Attempting to make a side-scroll carousel, where I wish to keep element hidden and then have them scroll into view.

In order to allow my sub-container (containing my images) to be wider than its parent, I've used `position: absolute`. I had hoped then adding `overflow-x: hidden` would allow the additional content to not be shown outside the div until I scroll across. However, this does not work.

I attempted to add `position: relative` to the container but this simply makes my side-scroll carousel constrained to the size of the parent.

**How can I make the images that sit outside the grey area not be visible?**

```css
.carousel {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 345px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.carousel-image-holder {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class=carousel>
  <div class=carousel-image-holder>
    <img src=https://placekitten.com/75/100 />
    <img src=https://placekitten.com/75/100 />
    <img src=https://placekitten.com/75/100 />
    <img src=https://placekitten.com/75/100 />
    <img src=https://placekitten.com/75/100 />
    <img src=https://placekitten.com/75/100 />
    <img src=https://placekitten.com/75/100 />
  </div>
</div>
```